# Error with tablesorter JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am  trying to implement tablesorter jquery in my asp.net MVC 4 application. I am getting the following error "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'tablesorter'". I have found similar issue posted on this site and i tried all the posible solutions found and spent around 2 days to figure it out but no luck.

Here is the code for your review:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.metadata.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myTable1').tablesorter();
    }); 
</script>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SortedTable";
}
<h2>SortedTable</h2>
<table id="myTable1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Emp ID</th>
            <th>Employee Name</th>
            <th>Designation</th>
            <th>Dept</th>
            <th>DOB</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>Bob</td>
            <td>tech</td>
            <td>CS</td>
            <td>01-01-2005</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>101</td>
            <td>Arnold</td>
            <td>tech</td>
            <td>CS</td>
            <td>01-01-2001</td>
        </tr>>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

could anyone please point me out whats wrong with the above code.

Comment: Is `jquery-latest.js` and  `jquery-1.9.1.js` not the same framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing the jQuery library two times, so just leave the `jquery-latest.js` and remove `jquery-1.9.1.js`

Comment: thanks for pointing out. the crux is we must have only one referecne of Jquery file. Since i am using MVC-4 project, jquery-1.9.1.js file was also referenced in _Layout.cshtml file. When i removed the jquery-1.9.1.js file from _Layout.cshtml and also from the html page where i have to sort the table, everything started working. thanks.